# Grid and in-line editing

Tags: scrolling, grid

I am developing an application where I have a header and a list of lines.

The dilemma I am having is how to display an interface where the user can edit multiple lines at the same time in a user-friendly approach. The problem is that I have a number of fields (about 20) and I would like to display them all at once. This would result in horizontal scrolling (which is usually not recommended).

I am not sure which would be the best approach - whether to use this scrolling or perhaps a popup, or a section which expands etc...

I am sure I am not the first one with this problem and would like recommendations about best-practice for such a scenario.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot,it would be helpful

Comment: Is the editing function a primary action?

Comment: yes, I would like the "edit all lines at one time" approach. But I am afraid of the balance between "productivity" and "user-friendliness". I would like it to be productive (user can update it easily) but at the same time it has to be intuitive to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First approach**

The iTunes bulk edit functionality is a good solution for editing data. Actions you should execute by buttons above or below the table. See post:

[Bulk edit in tables](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/18332/best-way-to-do-bulk-edits-on-a-table)

**Second approach**

I have found a solution which allows to overwrite all data in column of selected rows (lightblue selection color) by editing value. IMO this solution is productively but not self-explanatory.

[image: Bulk editing by rowselection and data typing]

**But the correct solution it's depend on your use case scenario!!!**